# Why the uCallbackMessage of Shell_NotifyIcon not work when I run the program as administrator

Tags: c++, winapi

My operating system is Windows 11.

I want to make a console program hide in the system tray. So I create a hiding window and use Shell_NotifyIcon to implement it.

When I run the program, not as administrator, the program works well. However, when I run the program as administrator, the `uCallbackMessage` message of notifyIcon doesn't send to the message queue. I don't understand why it happens.

```cpp
    BOOL AddNotificationIcon()
    {
        NOTIFYICONDATA nid = { sizeof(nid) };
        nid.hWnd = message_hwnd;
        nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_SHOWTIP | NIF_GUID;
        nid.uCallbackMessage = WMAPP_NOTIFYCALLBACK;
        nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
        nid.guidItem = icon_guid;
        _tcscpy(nid.szTip, TEXT("FanViewer"));
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);

        // NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4 is prefered
        nid.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4;
        return Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETVERSION, &nid);
    }
    void Run()
    {
        std::thread t1([this] {
            message_hwnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("MessageWindow"),  
                TEXT("Message"),   
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CAPTION, 
                CW_USEDEFAULT,  
                CW_USEDEFAULT,  
                200,  
                200,  
                NULL, 
                NULL, 
                GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
                NULL  
            );
            ShowWindow(message_hwnd, SW_HIDE);
            auto result = AddNotificationIcon();
            if (!result || !(message_hwnd)) {
                Close();
            }
            MSG msg;
            while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        });
        t1.join();
    }
```

I create the NotifyIcon using these codes.

And I try to print some string when the program gets the `WMAPP_NOTIFYCALLBACK` message like these

```cpp
    LRESULT Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (message) {
        case WMAPP_NOTIFYCALLBACK:
            std::cout << "fff" << std::endl;
            switch (LOWORD(lParam)) {
            case NIN_SELECT:
                ShowWindow(console_hwnd, SW_SHOW);
                break;

            case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
            {
                POINT const pt = { LOWORD(wParam), HIWORD(wParam) };
                ShowContextMenu(hwnd, pt);
            }
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
                break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            break;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

When I run the program, not as the administrator, I can see "fff" from the console. But there is nothing when I run the program as administrator.

Comment: [`ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changewindowmessagefilterex).

Comment: Ok, I know, maybe I set a bad `uCallbackMessage `, I set another message to it randomly, and it works well